# I want to schedule a worker to show a notification when the device is plugged in and connected to the internet

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, job-scheduling, android-workmanager

Alright, I think the title is pretty self-explanatory...I have to use the WorkManager api to schedule a notification that will be displayed every time the device is connected to the internet and is charging(plugged-in). I managed to create a worker and make it display the notification, but the issue here is that it only shows the notification once. After that even if I disconnect/re-connect to wifi and unplug/plug the cable, it won't show the notification.

```
val notificationTriggerConstraint = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .build()
    val notificationWorker = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(notificationTriggerConstraint)
            .build()
```

---

```
class NotificationWorker(@NonNull context: Context, @NonNull workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {
override fun doWork(): Result {

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "CHANNEL")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Background job")
            .setContentText("Device is charging and connected to WIFI")
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Device is charging and connected to WIFI"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())

    return Result.SUCCESS
}}
```

These are the constraints and the worker which creates the notification. I can't use a PeriodicWorkRequest since that is not the way the application should work. Can anyone suggest an approach here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think that WorkManager is the best option in this case.**

In your particular case, you are using a `OneTimeWorkRequest` so, once this is run by the WorkManager, you need to enqueue it again (but it becomes tricky to enqueue it only when one of the two contrastraints are false).

A better approach would be to use a combination of the [`BatteryManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring) and the [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)
Unfortunately, I was constrained to use only the WorkManager, so the final solution was to use a periodic request, even though it was not exactly the perfect approach