# Android: receive ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED with application closed

Tags: android

A few years ago, I wrote a tiny application to apply some settings changes to my phone when the charging state changed.

To do this at the time, I registered a `receiver` in the manifest:

```xml
<receiver android:name=".services.PowerStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This receiver ran a few lines of code, and that was it. It worked perfectly.

Since API 26, this no longer works. I have to register the receiver at runtime, and it only seems to work while the app is open and for a while after it leaves foreground. I tried to switch methods, then tried using a `Service` to register the receiver with `START_STICKY`, to no avail.

How can I achieve the same effect with the current API restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that Google clamped down on anything that allows the app to run in the background over the past few API versions, and there are only a few things that are exempt, and they're all pretty hacky. With any of these, you'll probably want to do the following 2 things:

1. You'll need to make sure that your app is exempt from battery optimizations. You can either do it manually, or have your app [launch an intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114063/how-do-i-properly-fire-action-request-ignore-battery-optimizations-intent) that'll let the user do it easily.
2. You should also set your app Manifest with `android:persistent="true"`, and extend your Appication class to keep it running in the background

And then, here are a few ways that you can have your app "wake up" or stay running:

- Set up your app to have Notification Access with a [NotificationListenerService](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-notificationlistenerservice-example.html), and then launch your BroadcastReceiver inside `onListenerConnected()`. That will keep the service running in the background, and because your receiver was registered inside it, it'll keep that running as well
- Set up AlarmManager to periodically send your app an intent to wake it up, and then re-launch your BroadcastReceiver
- Set up Firebase push notifications to periodically wake up your app, and it can then spin up the BroadcastReceiver

I think you can also set up your app as an AccessibilityService, but I don't remember if that will run continuously in the background

**Edit**: I forgot that you can also use WorkManager to schedule periodic wake-ups, and check if the power is plugged in. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335853/how-to-create-a-job-with-workmanager-when-device-is-plugged-in) how to do it

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I will try these approaches and get back. How about foreground services? How are those treated by the system? Having a permanent notification is hardly ideal, but can it be marked as silent, so it doesn't bother me? If, as a user, I disable a notification channel, can it still be used for a foreground service? If you know, I'd appreciate the info

Comment: You can actually use work manager with ongoing work, which will automatically create a foreground notification for you. However, Google specifically states that if that notification is on a silent channel, it won't continue running the service. I don't know what happens if you make it a normal notification channel, but the user chooses to silence it

Comment: I've had this running for about a week now on a `NotificationListenerService`, with almost perfect results. The service still seems to die occasionally, but it's rare and I do believe a periodic wake-up with a nicely configured WorkManager task will take care of that. Thanks!